# Switch to test database using FastAPI and ormar

Tags: python, pytest, fastapi, ormar

I am trying ormar with FastAPI and struggling with testing.
Because I use Django in the majority of my projects, I am trying to separate my databases between development and testing. But I am struggling to do this.

The goal is basically, use PostgreSQL for development/production, but switch to SQLite when running pytest. And remove all data from the SQLite database when tests are done.(Imagine Django+Docker dev environment)

I've tried the following from the ormar documentation, but no luck.

```py
TEST_DB_URL = "sqlite:///../db.sqlite"

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="module")
def create_test_database():
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(TEST_DB_URL)
    metadata.create_all(engine)
    yield
    metadata.drop_all(engine)
```

After the above and when I try to do something with the database in tests(using pytest), the following error occurs.

```
====================================================================================== FAILURES =======================================================================================
_______________________________________________________________________________ test_user_registration ________________________________________________________________________________

db = <function db.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fb7d30c9820>

    @pytest.mark.asyncio
    async def test_user_registration(db):
>       users = await db(User.objects.all)

app/users/test_users.py:51: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
app/conftest.py:39: in wrapper
    return await func()
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/ormar/queryset/queryset.py:1016: in all
    rows = await self.database.fetch_all(expr)
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/databases/core.py:147: in fetch_all
    async with self.connection() as connection:
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/databases/core.py:251: in __aenter__
    raise e
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/databases/core.py:248: in __aenter__
    await self._connection.acquire()
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <databases.backends.postgres.PostgresConnection object at 0x7fb7d319e910>

    async def acquire(self) -> None:
        assert self._connection is None, "Connection is already acquired"
>       assert self._database._pool is not None, "DatabaseBackend is not running"
E       AssertionError: DatabaseBackend is not running

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/databases/backends/postgres.py:162: AssertionError
=============================================================================== short test summary info ===============================================================================
FAILED app/users/test_users.py::test_user_registration - AssertionError: DatabaseBackend is not running
```

My database setup looks like this and this works just fine saving data etc via regular API calls.

```py
import os

import databases
from fastapi import FastAPI
import sqlalchemy

from app.resources.utils import get_models_path_list

models_path_list = get_models_path_list()


def get_db_uri(*, user, password, host, db):
    return f'postgresql://{user}:{password}@{host}:5432/{db}'


DB_URL = get_db_uri(
    user=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_USER'),
    password=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_PASSWORD'),
    host='db',  # docker-composeのservice名
    db=os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB'),
)
database = databases.Database(DB_URL)
metadata = sqlalchemy.MetaData()


def setup_database(app: FastAPI):
    app.state.database = database

    @app.on_event("startup")
    async def startup() -> None:
        database_ = app.state.database
        if not database_.is_connected:
            await database_.connect()

    @app.on_event("shutdown")
    async def shutdown() -> None:
        database_ = app.state.database
        if database_.is_connected:
            await database_.disconnect()
```

Comment: what is this: 
`os.environ.get('POSTGRES_DB')` returning?

Also, is the database actually running and configured correctly, this error: `AssertionError: DatabaseBackend is not running` suggests it is not.

Comment: @Nandostyle to answer the first quest, it returns a string of a db name, for example, "invoice_db".

Comment: I know that, I meant to understand if it is returning the correct name of the database. there may lie the issue. Capitalization is important

Comment: can you show your test function where you are trying to do stuff with the db?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I struggled there too. First of all [this](https://github.com/collerek/ormar/discussions/136) discussion will help you.
Crux here.
You need to use an environment variable that points to your sqlite db.
I did use BaseSettings from FastAPI and added this method there

```
def get_db_uri(self) -> str:
    # set the below in your environment file when running tests
    if self.TESTING:
        return "sqlite:///../db.sqlite"

    if self.PRODUCTION:
        return self._get_db_uri(
            user="root",
            passwd=self.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
            host=self.AURORA_DB_URI,
            port=self.POSTGRES_PORT,
            db=self.POSTGRES_DB,
        )

    return self._get_db_uri(
        user=self.POSTGRES_USER,
        passwd=self.POSTGRES_PASSWORD,
        host=self.POSTGRES_HOST,
        port=self.POSTGRES_PORT,
        db=self.POSTGRES_DB,
    )
```

One other thing which i was missing was that fixture for dropping and creating tables. You already have that there.

```
TEST_DB_URL = "sqlite:///../db.sqlite"

@pytest.fixture(autouse=True, scope="module")
def create_test_database():
    engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(TEST_DB_URL)
    metadata.create_all(engine)
    yield
    metadata.drop_all(engine)
```

You can use [pytest-env](https://github.com/MobileDynasty/pytest-env) for setting environment variables in tests.